# How to access SQL Server System Functions like CAST, CONVERT using 3 part naming covention

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Like below, am trying to access System Function CAST() using Database name as prefix but isn't working.

```
SELECT Master.Dbo.CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME2),UserDB.dbo.CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME2)
```

Error : `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.`

Replacing 'dbo' with 'sys' or '..' didn't work and it appears that CAST works stand-alone only without any prefix.

Those 2 Databases has different Compat Levels and so the output differs which is what I want to capture in one go.

Does someone know how to make it work, please?

Comment: That is not the correct way to use CAST. Post an example of the output your getting vs the output that you want. What version of SQL Sever are you using? What compatibility levels are you wanting?

Comment: @BillRuhl - yes, that's not usual way of using CAST. DATETIME2 variances on SQL Server 2012 & 2016/2017 is what is am trying to expose to my colleagues. But as I said wanted to do in one go while work around is to USE DBName and execute SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME2) individually on these DBs.

Comment: If you use CONVERT then you can specify a style...SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,GETDATE() ,121)

Comment: @BillRuhl - am not formatting the output but inherent output is different on these versions and is discussed here - [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/de5dbf3e-8c95-40f4-9e31-b71f1f31983d/change-in-datetime2-implementation-in-sql-server-2016) . Please tell me if you know way to access CAST using 3 part naming convention.

Comment: `CAST`, `CONVERT` and other [built-in functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/functions) are not schema-qualified objects and can't be accessed with multipart names, as opposed to [system functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/system-functions-for-transact-sql) (and user-defined functions, of course).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display how the calculations for a `datetime` to `datetime2` differs, then you need to run the statements within the context of the 2 different databases with the different compatibility settings, like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE Test2019DB; --I am Running 2019 Preview Edition
GO

CREATE DATABASE Test2012DB;
GO

ALTER DATABASE Test2012DB SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;
GO

USE Test2019DB;
GO
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(7),CONVERT(datetime,'2019-11-04T11:23:47.123')) AS DT2_2019;
GO

USE Test2012DB;
GO
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(7),CONVERT(datetime,'2019-11-04T11:23:47.123')) AS DT2_2012;
GO

USE master;
GO

--clean up
DROP DATABASE Test2019DB;
DROP DATABASE Test2012DB;
```

Return values:

```
DT2_2019
2019-11-04 11:23:47.1233333 

DT2_2012
2019-11-04 11:23:47.1230000
```

Comment: Moreover, you can put these statements in actual functions, and then access *those* using three-part naming (`SELECT Test2012DB.dbo.CastAsDateTime2(...)`), which comes closest to what the OP was after. (Of course, care should be taken with creating any objects in `master`.)

Comment: Everyone's answering my need but I was also wanting to know if 3 part naming invocation is possible for such System Functions. Appears like to be not supported.

Comment: *"I was also wanting to know if 3 part naming invocation is possible for such System Functions"* No, @LonelyRogue , as they (things like `CAST`,`CONVERT`, etc) aren't system functions in the same sense as the ones you find in the `sys` schema. They aren't part a database object.